# Преобразовать теги в текст jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, текст, теги

Необходимо через jQuery преобразовать теги в простой текст. Есть страница, назовем её content.php к которой через jQuery осуществляется запрос со страницы edit.php, полученные данные уходят в редактор на странице edit.php. В том числе нужно вытянуть `title`. Вытянуть вместе с тегами получилось, нужно или выдернуть содержимое `title`, или преобразовать вместе с тегами в текст.

Comment: Привет, можете мой ответ отметить как правильный? Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Используем регулярные-выражения, находим текст и достаем его.

```js
var regex = /<title>(.+)<\/title>/g;
var str = `<title>content</title>`;
var m;

m = regex.exec(str);
console.log(m[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

При помощи [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) и его метода `parseFromString`:

```js
let nodesStr = '<head><title>Title text</title></head><body><div>Text in div</div><p>Text in p</p><section>Text in section</section></body>'

let generatedDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(nodesStr, 'text/html');

console.log('Title text:', generatedDocument.querySelector('title').innerHTML);
console.log('Div text:', generatedDocument.querySelector('div').innerHTML);
console.log('P text:', generatedDocument.querySelector('p').innerHTML);
console.log('Section text:', generatedDocument.querySelector('section').innerHTML);
```